# Grails g:each , Using fieldvalue or direct access Difference

Tags: grails, gsp

```
<g:each in="${business}" status="i" var="businessInstance">
<tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even' }">
<td>${fieldValue(bean: businessInstance, field: "id") }</td>
<td>${businessInstance.id}</td>
</tr>
</g:each>
```

In above example, both first and second table data results same value. Is there any difference in those two cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fieldValue` escapes the value by calling `encodeAsHTML()` to guard against XSS attacks, so it's much safer to use. It also formats numbers according the the current locale.

Comment: Does configuring grails.views.default.codec = 'html' makes the ${} act as the ${fieldValue} (I'm working on Grails 2.2.0?) ?